# "А мне ваши цветы не нравятся(,) и что с того?" — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть ли правило, по которому запятая необходима? Если постановка таковой не требуется — объясните, пожалуйста, почему. Уж очень хочется ее здесь поставить.

Comment: @shampar Зачем Вы поправили первое предложение? Считаете его невежливым? Я серьёзно спрашиваю, без подколов. Допускаю, что поправить действительно правильно было, просто сомневаюсь.

Comment: Да не невежливым, Артём, — просто неуместным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**А мне ваши цветы не нравятся, и что с того?**

Можно поставить запятую,  можно поставить тире. А правило простое: в сложносочиненном предложении перед союзом И ставится запятая при отсутствии общих элементов.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Запятыми разделяются предикативные части сложносочиненного предложения (простые предложения), между которыми стоят союзы.

Итак, это сложносочиненное предложение, "и что с того" —  самостоятельная предикативная единица фразеологического характера  со значением "и что из того следует".

Общих элементов нет, вопросительным является только второе предложение, поэтому запятая перед союзом И ставится. Тире —  авторский знак при увеличенной паузе.

Примеры

Да, он давно знал Леонида Курмышова, **и что с того**? [Александра Маринина. Последний рассвет (2013)]

**Ну и что с того**, что вам говорили? [Владимир Войнович.  (1976)]

Война? **Ну и что с того**? Война придёт и уйдёт. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

Да, мир погибнет и кончится ― **и что с того**? [Виктор Пелевин. Любовь к трем цукербринам (2014)]